# Rails - 4.2.1 undefined method `or' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use the `or` statement with @verses but for some reason I keep getting `activerecord` relation error.

searches_controller.rb

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @verses = Verse.where("LOWER(verse) LIKE LOWER(?)", params[:search_term]).or.where("LOWER(verse) LIKE LOWER(?)", "%#{params[:search_term]}%")
    @books = Book.where("LOWER(book_name) LIKE LOWER(?)", "%" + params[:search_term] + "%")
    @versions = Version.where("LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(?)", "%" + params[:search_term] + "%")
    @results = @verses.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    # @json = @results.map { |item| {name: item.name, link: url_for(item)} }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      # format.json { render json: @json }
    end
  end
end
```

The application error shows this

```
app/controllers/searches_controller.rb:3:in `search'
```

Which makes me think it is the use of the .or in the @verses

Here is the full application trace:

```
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
rack-mini-profiler (0.9.3) lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:106:in `block in profile_method'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
rack-mini-profiler (0.9.3) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:276:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: I didn't even heard that Rails had `or` method

Comment: if you have long queries, I'd say it's a good idea to create a class for it

Comment: As far as I know, this feature has been merged to rails master branch but has not been released yet.

Comment: It is there on the master https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/null_relation.rb#L87-89 . Link of the full commit : https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9e42cf019f2417473e7dcbfcb885709fa2709f89

Comment: @AmitThawait Ok,. it is in master... I checked [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/querying.rb)..and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2366cc5e3488878adf3459fb1221d0b08a7254f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/querying.rb#L12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce long queries of controller by creating Scope.

**in model**

```
scope :find_verse, ->(search_term) { where("LOWER(verse) LIKE LOWER (?) OR LOWER(verse) LIKE LOWER(%#{search_term}%)", search_term ) }
```

**In controller**

```
@verses = Verse.find_verse(params[:search_term])
```

Comment: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SearchesController#search` Couldn't find Version without an ID, but I think that is not related to this specific problem.

Comment: where you have written query to find Version?

Comment: models/version.rb 
`def self.find_version(params)
    Version.friendly.find(params['version'])
  end`

Comment: Check logs and find out what value is the in `params['version']`